# Force browser to download a link which is not same origin in <a> tag html5

Tags: html

How to force mobile browser to download a `.jpg` file on click from **another** website. so far i tried:

```
<a href="https://anotherwebsite.com/example.jpg" target="_blank" download>Click To Download</a>
```

I found two workarounds for this problem (using `javascript` or `php`). I use `php` to bypass the problem. I create a file named `download.php` with this code in it:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    if (!is_null($_GET['link']) && !empty($_GET['link'])) {
        $file = $_GET['link'];
        try {
            header('Content-type: image/*');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
            readfile($file);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

then I change the download links to this:

```
<a href="download.php?link=https://anotherwebsite.com/example.jpg">Click To Download</a>
```

is there another way that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot work by definition. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

> This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

Comment: [mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874009) and [chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714373). so is this a bug for browsers or it because of cross-origin downloads are dangerous?

Comment: It may not  be a bug but by design. See the [W3C recommendation of HTML5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#dom-htmlanchorelement-download). It is a bit hard to follow though. From what i understand is that a browser may not follow a link which is outside the current browsing context.

Comment: To allow a file to be downloaded from another origin you need to set a response header (server side that is). 
"Content-Disposition": "attachment"
Or if you want set a certain name:
"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='abc.jpg'"