# How to download file from another URL with MV3 chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm using MV3 to create a chrome extension which injects a download button onto the document body. I'm trying to get that download button to download an example PDF hosted on another URL, but am unable to do so. When I click on the button, Chrome just opens the PDF in the current tab. I need to instead download it to the computer like a regular file. I have the download permission in my manifest, but am unsure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is where the download button is stored is my contentScript.JS file.

```
 function createModal() {
            var auroraModal = document.createElement('div');
            auroraModal.className = '_aurora__modal';
            auroraModal.id = '_aurora__modal';

            var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.download = "Example.pdf";
            downloadLink.href = "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
            downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Download';

            auroraModal.innerHTML = '<p>Woo-hoo <strong>'+dataFromPromise+'</strong>! Your custom PDF is ready!</p>';
            auroraModal.appendChild(downloadLink)
            document.body.appendChild(auroraModal)
        }
```

And here is my manifest.JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Aurora Extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Aurora extension attempt with FB9 and MV3",
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "downloads"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*.stackoverflow.com/*"],
  "background": { "service_worker": "background/index.js" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content/index.js"],
      "css": ["content/coupon.css"],
      "matches": ["https://*.stackoverflow.com/*"]
    }
  ],
  "action": { "default_popup": "pages/popup/index.html" }
}
```

Comment: Please see this. [Force browser to download a link which is not same origin in <a> tag html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452312/force-browser-to-download-a-link-which-is-not-same-origin-in-a-tag-html5)

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Thank you for this! I suppose that makes sense, but maybe there's a way to still achieve this via the chrome.downloads function?

Comment: This because the server doesn't respond with `Content-Disposition: attachment` header. You can set it manually for this URL using [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) but it's simpler to use chrome.downloads as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! I'll attempt this in a moment; would this solution work within a content script?

Comment: It depends. If you want to set declarativeNetRequest rule just for this URL just in this tab then it should be created using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules in a background script, a popup script, or a script inside web_accessible_resources iframe inside the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used `content scripts` and `service worker`.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "chrome.downloads.download used content_scripts + service_worker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "downloads"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.js

```js
console.log("matches.js");

const button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerText = "button";

button.onclick = () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("");
  console.log("Send");
}

document.body.insertBefore(button, document.body.firstElementChild);
```

background.js

```js
console.log("background.js");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Receive");
  chrome.downloads.download({
    filename: "Example.pdf",
    url: "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can't tell you how much of a relief it was to plug this into my code and have it suddenly work again; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please user `chrome.downloads.download`.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "chrome.downloads.download",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "downloads"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.downloads.download({
  filename: "Example.pdf",
  url: "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting this! I've implemented your solution but I'm getting this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'download')

var auroraD= document.createElement('button')
            auroraD.innerText = 'download';
            auroraD.addEventListener("click", dURL)

function dURL(){
            console.log("attempting to download!")
            chrome.downloads.download({
                filename: "Example.pdf",
                url: "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
            });
        }

Comment: Have you confirmed that my sample works?

Comment: I just tried with a brand new folder and it seems to have worked; thank you! However, it's not actually working in my project, and I'm unsure why. Any thoughts on how I could problem-solve this? I'm not sure if it changes things, but I'm attempting to call the download function in my contentscript.js, not the pop-up.

Comment: Most APIs don't work with Content scripts. [Understand content script capabilities
](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#capabilities)

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Any ideas on how I could still have an injected download button work? I'm quite new to coding in chrome extensions, so I'm unsure if maybe there's a way to pass the download variable somehow to the content script? Would you recommend I try anything?